# Not sure why but my code is breaking the command prompt (possible infinite loop)

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

So I've been having a go at the advent of code challenges. Currently I'm on day 2 and there seems to be an issue with the following code when I run it through node.js on the command prompt:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

var valid = fs.readFileSync("input2.txt", "utf8")
var validArr = valid.split("\n")

function validate() {
  var validPasswords = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < validArr.length;i++) {
    var low =  validArr[i].match(/\d+/g)[0];
    var high = validArr[i].match(/\d+/g)[1];
    var password = validArr[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[1];
    var letter = validArr[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[0];

    if (test(password, low, high, letter)) {
        validPasswords++
    }
  }

  console.log(validPasswords);
}

test = function(password, low, high, letter) {
    var count = 0 
    for (i=0; password.length; i++) {
        if (password.charAt(i) === letter) {
            count++
        }  
    }

    if (low <= count && count <= high) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false 
    }   
}

validate();
```

The problem arises when I move the `if (low <= count && count <= high)` statement out of the for loop in the function "test". Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: To clarify, when I run it on the command prompt it gets stuck in what seems like an infinite loop, where I can't type anything or exit the action.

Comment: always declare your variables, your condition is always truthy in the loop (as long as it has a length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop's condition is incorrectly set:

```
for (i=0; password.length; i++) {
```

You are saying that as long as `password.length` is true, keep looping. So, as long as `password.length` is not zero, it converts to `true` and you loop forever.

What you should be doing is saying that as long as the loop counter (`i`) is less than the `password.length` keep looping:

```
for (i=0; i < password.length; i++) {
```

Comment: @PeterMcNulty You're welcome. Don't forget to "up vote" all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the answer" by clicking the checkmark at the top left.